# Accessing JSON elements in PHP

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode, web-services

PHP noob here. I am building an iPhone app that is sending JSON blobs to a web server. On the server side I am receiving the JSON and trying to access the 3 fields that the object contains.

Two weird things are happening to me that I could not figure out how to fix:

1. I am not getting anything back when printing out the decoded object($post_data below).
2. I am actually able to print the full object back in Xcode when printing the object without decoding ($content below) but have no idea how to access the various fields in the object.

My PHP code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root", "") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_data = json_decode($content , true);
echo $content; --> prints the object properly 
echo $post_data; --> does not print anything
echo $content->lat; --> does not print anything
```

My JSON object:

```
{
  "lat" : 37.33233141,
  "long" : -122.0312186,
  "speed" : 0
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP json\_decode return empty array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848625/php-json-decode-return-empty-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because `json_decode($content, true)` is returning an array, which has problems displaying if you echo the container.

Try doing `echo $post_data['lat'];`

you can also try using `print_r($post_data);` to have it output the actual contents of the variable so you can see if something isn't working properly

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I tried literally every single option but this is working! Would you mind a follow up question? Can I use '$post_data['lat']' as is if I want to store this parameter in a database? Thanks!!

Comment: definitely. Because using `$post_data['lat']` will essentially replace the variable with it's contents in place. So you could be doing something like `"UPDATE TABLE current_location SET lat = '".$post_data['lat']."', long = '".$post_data['long']."' WHERE current_user = '".$user_id."' LIMIT 1";`